# Tomcat over ssl

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I am trying to setup tomcat over ssl. I received a certificate from my hosting company. I have copied the certificate text to a file name.crt and placed in the /ja/bin dir.

I have create a tomcat.keystore file in the same dir.

I have loaded the name.crt via the keytool. I get the message that the certificate is loaded.

The problem I am facing is that I can connect over port 8443 but the certificate is not trusted because it tells me it is a self signed certificate. However the certificate I got from my hosting company is certified via Commodo so should be regarded as trusted. I loaded the certificate content from this certificate into a file I created named: name.crt

I have altered the server.xml with the following lines:

Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_73/bin/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="*******" 
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"

(I have commented out the psswd)

Question: is it possible to create your own .crt file with the certificate info from a certified certificate? Or should I:

- create keystore file
- create csr via the keystore
- ask for a certificate via a certification authority using the csr file that is generated via the keystore file
- and install the received certificate on the server via the keytool

In other words: do I need to ask for a certificate using the csr that is created via the keystore file or can I use a certificate that is already issued by my hosting company with a keystorefile that I create after the certificate has been issued?

Kind regards,

Michel

Comment: Are you reading and following these?  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: yes, the only thing is that I already have the certificate. the manuals all talk about generating the csr file to get the certificate. I already have the certificate

Comment: I think the manuals assume that you are creating a self-signed certificate.  You got a legit one; all the steps that follow should be the same.

Comment: so I copied the __ -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGCDCCA etc. -----END CERTIFICATE----- text to a file called name.crt and used the keytool to import and link the certicicate in the keystore file.. That should be the right approach then?

Comment: If the intermediate certificate is not included in the file, I'm not sure it would work just using it straight off. How to add that _should_ be documented by Comodo though if it's required.

Comment: The issue was that the private key did not mach the one that was used for ordering the certificate